Integrating $\sin(2\arcsin(x))dx$
Here is my work for the following integral that I would like someone to double-check.
$$\int\sin(2\arcsin(x))\,dx$$
Taking $t=\arcsin x, x= \sin t \Rightarrow \cos{t}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$
$$\int \sin{2t}\cos{t}\,dt$$
$$\because \sin{2\theta}=2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}$$
$$2\int\sin{t}\cos^2{t}\,dt$$
Taking $\cos{t}=u\Rightarrow -\sin{t}\,dt=du$
$$-2\int u^2\,du$$
$$=-\frac{2u^3}{3}+C$$
$$=-\frac{2(\cos{t})^3}{3}+C$$
Since $\sin{t}=x\Rightarrow \cos{t}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{t}}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$
So my final answer is: $\frac{-2(1-x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{3}+C$
I don't see any obvious mistakes but I am unsure about the substitution within the substitution.

The final exponent is $3/2$ (this is just a typo). A part from that seems good to me. You can check it by differentiation (and noting an alternative form for the original function).

More explicitly, $\sin(2\hbox{arcsin}(x))=2\sin(\hbox{arcsin}x)\cos(\hbox{arcsin}(x))=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}.$ Then you can do the integral with a single substitution (but there is no fundamental problem with repeated ones!)
